# Cannot bind volume using Windows Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm having trouble with a volume in my docker-compose.yml.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: pg_provi_promentheus
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/resources/config/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
      - pg_provi_prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
      # - "-storage.local.path=/prometheus"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: pg_provi_node_exporter
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: pg_provi_grafana
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/resources/config/grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning:ro
      - pg_provi_grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  pg_provi_prometheus_data:
  pg_provi_grafana_data:
```

I constantly get this error message on startup:

```
[INFO] starting containers
Creating network "pg_provi_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "pg_provi_pg_provi_prometheus_data" with default driver
Creating volume "pg_provi_pg_provi_grafana_data" with default driver
Creating pg_provi_promentheus   ... error
Creating pg_provi_node_exporter ... done

ERROR: for pg_provi_promentheus  Cannot start service prometheus: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/mnt/c/Entwicklung/home/_workspace/workspace/provinzial-prometheus-grafana/src/main/localhost/pg_provi/resources/config/prometheus.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/643795a7aff240086c1d48371fd7ded76a52d70a53299b01a253c25a529ec0e5/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/643795a7aff240086c1d48371fd7ded76a52d70a53299b01a253c25a529ec0e5/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

ERROR: for prometheus  Cannot start service prometheus: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/mnt/c/Entwicklung/home/_workspace/workspace/provinzial-prometheus-grafana/src/main/localhost/pg_provi/resources/config/prometheus.yml\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/643795a7aff240086c1d48371fd7ded76a52d70a53299b01a253c25a529ec0e5/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/643795a7aff240086c1d48371fd7ded76a52d70a53299b01a253c25a529ec0e5/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Same docker-compose.yml on linux works perfectly fine. I don't get why I cannot mount my prometheus.yml into my container.

Startup and shutdown is straight forward via `docker-compose up -d` and `docker-compose down -v`.

Anyone got an idea? Thanks guys.

Comment: Despite the fact this question belongs to https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ have you tried mounting with a dot (like ./resources....)? There is an issue on github users complain about exactly that on windows https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/424

Comment: Skip using `${PWD}` and put in the full path instead.

Comment: Turned out some local firewall settings prevented mounting volumes into the container. But thanks for your help guys. I'll remember serverfault and superuser.